# How to use build authenticated router with feathersjs , adminjs and mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs, adminjs

I am trying to use adminjs's build authenticated router with feathers express and mongoose but I just can't.

```js
import AdminJS from 'adminjs';
import {Mongoose} from 'mongoose';
import AdminJSMongoose from '@adminjs/mongoose';
import AdminJSExpress from "@adminjs/express";
import session from 'express-session';
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo';

const sessionOptions = MongoStore.create({
  collectionName: "sessions",
  mongoUrl: app.get('mongodb'),
  stringify: false,
  autoRemove: "interval",
  autoRemoveInterval: 1,
});

const adminRouter = AdminJSExpress.buildAuthenticatedRouter(
  admin, {
    authenticate,
    cookieName: 'admin',
    cookiePassword: 'password',
  },
  null, {
    store: sessionOptions,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'password',
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    },
    name: 'admin',
  }
)
app.use(admin.options.rootPath, adminRouter);
```

AdminJS dependencies versions:

```
"admin-bro": "^4.0.1",
"adminjs": "^6.7.5",
```

**What browsers do you see the problem on?**  `Safari`

**Relevant log output**  `invalid react hook call`

**Relevant code that's giving you issues**  `/admin/login` page

I tried almost everything.